# How does memory allocation in FUSE programs work?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, malloc, fuse

I am following an example [FUSE Tutorial](http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~pfeiffer/fuse-tutorial/) to understand how FUSE works in linux. In the example all the dynamic data is allocated using malloc, and passed in as user data to the `fuse_main` function. This data is later accessible for any fuse calls. These calls need not be from the same process. How does this work?

To make the question more clear ,
i run the main `bbfs` program with `../src/bbfs rootdir mountdir` to mount the file system. It is in the main() of [bbfs.c](http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~pfeiffer/fuse-tutorial/src/bbfs.c) that the malloc is called. The bbfs program also defines several fuse function calls. But this program exits after the filesystem is mounted.

How can other programs(or the kernel) which calls `read()` or `open()` on the mounted filesystem

1.access the memory allocated using malloc by the bbfs program if it has already exited? Wouldn't the OS free up the memory allocated using malloc after the program `bbfs` exited?

2.access the defined functions, if the process that defined them had already exited? Where would the `object code` of the fuse functions reside after the process exited?

I am a bit confused about the lifetimes of the object code and the heap memory objects here and how other programs (or the kernel) use it later. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: The program doesn't exit. It's forking and running in the background. The rest of your question is moot.

Comment: that makes sense. what do i do with this question? could you post this as an answer so that i can close it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your question is based on a false assumption:

> … But [the FUSE server] exits after the filesystem is mounted.

It's not actually exiting at all. It's forking into the background and continuing to run as long as the filesystem is mounted.

While it's running, everything works as normal.